# Dynamic Pivot Queries with dynamic dates as column header in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the actual result set from SQL Server

```
+-----------+--------+------------------+
| Dates     | Orders | Cancelled Orders |
+-----------+--------+------------------+
|2016-01-17 |  100   |       50         |             
|2016-01-18 |  120   |       20         |                
|2016-01-20 |  150   |       30         |    
+-----------+--------+------------------+
```

I need to pivot the table as shown below

```
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|Dates     | 2016-01-17 | 2016-01-18 | 2016-01-19 |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|Orders    |    100     | 120        |  150       | 
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
|Cancelled |            |            |            |
|Orders    |     50     |  20        |   30       |
+----------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Can anyone give me suggestions in writing query? Here dates have to come dynamically.

Comment: SQL server is a relational database and the record sets must have a predefined columns definitions, meaning the number of columns and the names and types must be known in advance. You can however decided that you will support up to X columns and put the date as one of the data rows....

Comment: Search for dynamically pivoting. There have been a lot of questions and answers for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query..it will help you

```
select * into #tempp from(

select '2016-01-17' as DATES,100 ORDERS,50 CANCELED_ORDERS
UNION ALL
SELECT '2016-01-18',120,20
UNION ALL
SELECT '2016-01-20',150,30
)AS A

--SELECT * FROM #tempp

declare @pivotcols nvarchar(max),@unpivotcols nvarchar(max),@SQLQUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
select @pivotcols=stuff((select ','+quotename(dates) from #tempp for xml path('')),1,1,'')
--select @pivotcols

select @unpivotcols=stuff((select ','+name from tempdb.sys.columns where object_id =
object_id('tempdb..#tempp') and name<>'DATES' for xml path('')),1,1,'')
--select @unpivotcols

SET @SQLQUERY=N'select * from (
SELECT * FROM #tempp
)as a
unpivot (AMOUNTS FOR Dates  in ('+@unpivotcols+N') 
) AS UNPI
PIVOT (MAX(AMOUNTS) FOR DATES IN ('+@pivotcols+N')
)AS A'

PRINT @SQLQUERY

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQLQUERY
```

The output will be like.

```
    +-----------------+------------+------------+------------+
    |      Dates       | 2016-01-17 | 2016-01-18 | 2016-01-20|
    +-----------------+------------+------------+------------+
    | CANCELED_ORDERS |         50 |         20 |         30 |
    | ORDERS          |        100 |        120 |        150 |
    +-----------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Mahesh,Instead of hardcode of dates can you suggest me

Comment: @kallaparijoseph what you want to ask exactly.the header of your question itself showing that you want ~Dynamic query~ and the code i have provided you is also dynamic one.just go through the code once.

Comment: shA.t answer helped me.Thanks for your suggestions mahesh

Answer (score 0):

You need to break your query in two parts.

In first part using **coalesce** function of SQL concatenates your dates same as pivot query except the argument.

In second part make your main pivot query using dynamic SQL and instead of static dates pass your variable which hold dates ( which you have got in first part )

Below is my query which I run in my project you have to replace your table logic inside it.

```
        Create Table #Temp (Salesdays int)

    Insert into #Temp (Salesdays)values(7) 
    Insert into #Temp (Salesdays)values(14) 
    Insert into #Temp (Salesdays)values(30) 
    Insert into #Temp (Salesdays)values(90) 
    Insert into #Temp (Salesdays)values(180) 
    Insert into #Temp (Salesdays)values(365) 


    DECLARE @PivotColumns nVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @PivotColumns = COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',[' + cast([Salesdays] as varchar(5))+']', '['+cast([Salesdays] as varchar(5))+']') 
    FROM #Temp
    Print @PivotColumns


    Declare @SQLQuery nVarchar(max)=N'Select
    SellerSKU, 
    MarketPlaceCode,
    isnull([7],0) as   [SalesData_7],
    isnull([14],0) as  [SalesData_14],
    isnull([30],0) as  [SalesData_30],
    isnull([90],0) as  [SalesData_90],
    isnull([180],0) as [SalesData_180], 
    isnull([365],0) as [SalesData_365] 
    from
    (
    Select 
    SellerSKU,
    MPDetail.MarketPlaceCode,
    Sum(QuantityShipped)QuantityShipped,
    Case when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 7 ) then 7
            when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 14 ) then 14
            when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 30 ) then 30
            when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 90 ) then 90
            when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 180 ) then 180 
            when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 365 ) then 365 END as SalesDays
    from OrderDetail
    inner join MPDetail
    on(OrderDetail.MPDetailID=MPDetail.MPDetailID)
    inner join  OrderItemDetail
    on(OrderDetail.OrderDetailID=OrderItemDetail.OrderDetailID)

    Group by SellerSKU,MPDetail.MarketPlaceCode,Case when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 7 ) then 7
            when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 14 ) then 14
            when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 30 ) then 30
            when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 90 ) then 90
            when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 180 ) then 180 
            when (DATEDIFF(dd,OrderDetail.PurchaseDate,getDate()) <= 365 ) then 365 END 
    )
    as SalesData
    pivot
    (
        Min(QuantityShipped) For SalesDays in('+@PivotColumns+')
    )AS USAPivotData'

    Print @SQLQuery

    exec (@SQLQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    CREATE TABLE #t  ( Dates DATE, Orders INT,CancelledOrders INT)
    INSERT INTO #t
    SELECT '2016-01-17',100 ,50  UNION         
    SELECT '2016-01-18',120 ,20  UNION         
    SELECT '2016-01-20',150 ,30  



    DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(max),@sql VARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @cols=ISNULL(@cols+',[','[')+CONVERT(VARCHAR,dates)+']' FROM #t GROUP BY Dates
    PRINT @cols

    SET @sql=' SELECT *  FROM (
       SELECT c.t,c.v,dates FROM #t
       CROSS APPLY(VALUES(''Orders'',Orders),(''CancelledOrders'',CancelledOrders))AS c(t,v)
   ) AS t
   PIVOT(MAX(v) FOR dates IN ('+@cols+')) p'

   EXEC(@sql)
```

```
t               2016-01-17  2016-01-18  2016-01-20
--------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
CancelledOrders 50          20          30
Orders          100         120         150
```

Comment: Thanks Nolan,Instead of hardcoding  dates in query can you suggest me

Comment: @kallaparijoseph If the columns of [Orders] and [CancelledOrders] also are variable, I think the script of Mahesh.K is helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Without using pivot options of SQL Server and an old version can be something like this:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '', @sqla nvarchar(max) = '', @sqlb nvarchar(max) = '', @sqlc nvarchar(max) = '';
select  
    @sqla = @sqla + N',case when Dates = ''' + Dates + N''' then Orders end [' + Dates + N']',
    @sqlb = @sqlb + N',case when Dates = ''' + Dates + N''' then [Cancelled Orders] end [' + Dates + N']',
    @sqlc = @sqlc + N',max([' + Dates + ']) [' + Dates + ']'
from yourTable;
select @sql = N'select Dates' + @sqlc  + N' from (select ''Orders'' Dates' + @sqla + 
              N' from yourTable union all select ''Cancelled Orders'' Dates' + @sqlb + 
              N' from yourTable) t group by Dates';
exec(@sql);
```