# Pivot table in SQL Server on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that shows data like this

[image: Data in Table]

I need data in this format

```
              GIN      APINV        AR Rec       Requisitions
Total         8          11           77
Pending       7           6           77
New           1          77           0
Approved      0           5           0
Rejected      1           0           0
```

And so on...

What I already know is I have to use `PIVOT` but I have only worked with `PIVOT` using a single column.

Comment: Are the number of columns in your expected output fixed, or could they vary/be unknown?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please follow this link and it is working too. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41712456/4874225

Answer (score 0):

Combination of `CROSS APPLY` and `PIVOT` should do:

```
select *
from (
    select t.appname, x.status, x.val
    from your_table t
    cross apply (
        values 
            ('Total', t.total),
            ('Pending', t.pending),
            ('New', t.New),
            ('Approved', t.Approved),
            ('Rejected', t.Rejected)
    ) x (status, val)
) t pivot (
    sum(val) 
    for appname in (
        [GIN],[APINV],....
    )
);
```